# Is there a way to not support my app from iPad or selected iPhone versions?

Tags: ios, appstore-approval

I had submitted my app as Universal a long time ago and now I need to remove it from the iPad section and few iPhone versions such as 4,5,5S. Is there a way I can achieve this or do I need to show custom not supported screen to user when they install on such devices. Will apple reject my app for this reason?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For restricting your app to only iPhones devices after the app was already published on App Store you should reupload new version of your app to App Store by simply just changing target devices to iPhone only(with different Bundle Identifier of course).

About restricting your app to stop supporting older devices(4,5,5S) you should change your iOS version compatibility. For example iOS 13 is supported on iPhone 6s and newer devices so user won't be able to use it on older devices. Apple should handle this on their own.

There are some alternatives to restrict your app to specific devices with **Required device capabilities** key which you can find in your Info.plist file. But I don't think apple will accept this, if this features are not actually used in your app.

Here is the documentation about [UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/DeviceInformation/Reference/iOSDeviceCompatibility/DeviceCompatibilityMatrix/DeviceCompatibilityMatrix.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013599-CH17-SW1) in case you need it.

Answer (score -1):

You can only restrict user from downloading newer versions of your app from App Store ,By changing your apps deployment info in Xcode general tab.

By changing device type from Universal to iPhone only and Deployment target to iOS 13 which in supported by device above 6s. Then user will not be able to download on older versions.

Or you can restrict user access in your app by putting device specific checks and showing your custom ui for unsupported versions. But for this apple may reject your app  if it fails in every case for specific device.

But both type of changes you have to upload newer version of app on App Store.

Comment: Apple will not let you change an existing universal app to iPhone-only. It would need to be a new app with a new bundle id.

Comment: @rmaddy Will it allow us to add the iPad support in a later stage if we have only provided the iPhone support at the begining. (Just the reverse of the question asked!)